# RuntimeError: shape '[8192]' is invalid for input of size 8256

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn import functional as F 

batch_size = 64
block_size = 128
max_iters = 5000
eval_interval = 200
learning_rate = 3e-4
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
eval_iters = 100

torch.manual_seed(5452)

with open('DiscordGPT_data.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

characters = sorted(list(set(text)))
vocab_size = len(characters)

stoi = { ch:i for i,ch in enumerate(characters) }
itos = { i:ch for i,ch in enumerate(characters) }
encode = lambda s: [stoi[c] for c in s]
decode = lambda l: ''.join(itos[i] for i in l)

data = torch.tensor(encode(text), dtype= torch.long)
n = int(0.9*len(data))
train_data = data[:n]
evaluation_data = data[n:]

def get_batch(split):
    data = train_data if split == 'train' else evaluation_data
    ix = torch.randint(len(data) - block_size, (batch_size,))
    x = torch.stack([data[i:i+block_size] for i in ix])
    y = torch.stack([data[i:i+block_size+1] for i in ix])
    x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)

    return x, y

@torch.no_grad()
def estimate_loss():
    out = {}
    model.eval()
    for split in ['train', 'val']:
        losses = torch.zeros(eval_iters)
        for k in range(eval_iters):
            X, Y = get_batch(split)
            logits, loss = model(X, Y)
            losses[k] = loss.item()
        out[split] = losses.mean()
    model.train()
    return out

class BigramLangModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, vocab_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.token_embedding_table = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, idx, targets = None):

        logits = self.token_embedding_table(idx)

        if targets is None:
            loss = None
        else:
            B, T, C = logits.shape
            logits = logits.view(B*T, C)
            targets = targets.view(B*T)
            loss = F.cross_entropy(logits, targets)

        return logits, loss
    
    def generate(self, idx, max_new_tokens):

        for _ in range(max_new_tokens):
            logits, loss = self(idx)
            logits = logits[:, -1, :]
            probs = F.softmax(logits, dim=-1)
            idx_next = torch.multinomial(probs, num_samples=1)
            idx = torch.cat((idx, idx_next), dim=1)

        return idx

model = BigramLangModel(vocab_size)
m = model.to(device)

optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(m.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for iter in range(max_iters):

    if iter % eval_interval == 0:
        losses = estimate_loss()
        print(f"step {iter}: train loss {losses['train']:.4f}, val loss {losses['val']:.4f}")
        
    xb, yb = get_batch('train')

    logits, loss = model(xb, yb)
    optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none = True)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

context = torch.zeros((1,1), dtype = torch.long, device = device)
print(decode(m.generate(context, max_new_tokens=500)[0].tolist()))
```

curious where this is going wrong, keeps giving the runtime error even when i reduce the batch and block size, adjusting the numbers doesn't really help. I am still pretty new to the ML/AI space so any pointers on how to move forward would be helpful. This is supposed to be a replication of Nanogpt and trying to figure it out myself.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.